# Can not connect to Twitter using Tweepy Streaming

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy, twitter-streaming-api

Trying to check whether connection established or not, but nothing happened

I used `on_connect` to understand but got nothing:

```
import tweepy
import time

class InOutStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def on_connect(self):
        print 'Connected'    

    def disconnect(self):
        if self.running is False:
            return
        self.running = False

    def on_friends(self, friends):
        print friends[0]

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler('code', 'code')
auth.set_access_token('code', 'code')

l = InOutStreamListener()    
streamer = tweepy.Stream(auth, l)

time.sleep(15)    
streamer.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only created a Stream, you didn't start it, see the [docs](http://tweepy.readthedocs.org/en/v3.4.0/streaming_how_to.html#step-2-creating-a-stream).

> In this example we will use filter to stream all tweets containing the
>   word python. The track parameter is an array of search terms to
>   stream.
>
> myStream.filter(track=['python'])

Comment: it worked to me. i used streamer.filter(follow=['5345']) for monitoring. I am just wondering how to monitor Direct Messages